# using grep to look for a phrase in shell output with While loop

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop, grep

Hello I'm new to shell scripting and looking to use a terminal command with   a `while loop` and `grep` for a certain phrase "TEST_PASS" or "Test_Skip" or "Test_Failed" in the output.

if the phrase "TEST_PASS" in the terminal output then exit the loop.

else if the phrase "Test_Skip" or "Test_Failed" is in the output then retry command again.

I thought it would go something like this:

```
while ! #Command# | grep -i "TEST_PASS"
```

any help would be great.

thanks much

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
<your command goes here> | grep -q "TEST_PASS"
retry=`echo $?`
while [ $retry -ne 0 ]
do
    <your command goes here> | grep -q "TEST_PASS"
    retry=`echo $?`
done
echo "Test Passed!"
```

Comment: I like it, but couldn't you avoid `output.txt` with `yourcommand | grep -q 'TEST_PASS'`?. Either way, good answer.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidC.Rankin! I'm a novice in scripting too, didn't know about the `-q` option! Just checked the man page and it's going to come in handy :)

Comment: It all comes with time. You have a good command of scripting, now it's just a matter of gathering the subtleties. `:)` (which is just an ongoing process of learning that no one truly gets to end of, except maybe Ed and Charles -- you will see here....)

Comment: Could you kindly explain how the code works ?  what does                           while [ $retry -ne 0 ]  do ?

Comment: @AliAshram `echo $?` gives the exit status of the last command run. 0 is success and any non-zero is failure. `$retry` is the exit status of your command (with `grep -q "TEST_PASS"`). If the exit status = 0, then your command produced TEST_PASS. If the exit status is anything other than 0, then your command produced Test_Failed or Test_Skipped.